# Desktop doesn't connect to 4k Smart TV

Tags: display, hdmi

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a HP Prodesk DM G5 (i5-9100T / Intel UHD Graphics 630). 
When connecting it via hdmi to a Samsung 4K Smart TV (7099 Series), the TV doesn't detect a signal. Only a few seconds after start up the purple Ubuntu screen turns black, then the TV informs, that it doesn't get a signal.

When connecting a 18.04 running laptop to the TV, it gets detected as a secondary screen without any issues.

I changed the display manager to lightdm, but nothing changed.

Can someone advise?

I am a not very experienced user and run out of options to fix this.

Thanks alot in advance!
Leo

Comment: Have you tried a different (especially shorter) cable?

Comment: Hi Danzel, thanks for the suggestion. I managed now to get the TV screen running, as a secondary Display in addition to a 27inch PC screen. However, it won't function as a standalone display. When trying to mirror the screens and plugging the PC screen of, it gets disconnected again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem with a Panasonic Smart TV, solved by selecting an "enhanced" option in the HDMI configuration of the TV.

Comment: Hi Pitchizig. Thank you so much, hours of research were solved by your input. It worked! Thanks again. Leo